# Looking for a tool that compares more than 3 hex files (.img) and can automatically resolve differences

Tags: editor, comparison, hex-viewer

I have a drive that isn't working (no filesystem), but I can image the drive.
 
I have multiple .img image files of the same 4GB drive (just clones of the drive) but they're all a bit different. ~50% of the bytes aren't identical between the two drive images.

We're collecting about 10 different images, and we want to 'combine' some/all of them, such that the output image contains the most common value for each byte from our 10 constituent images. I'm not much of a software dev, so I'm trying to avoid writing anything to do this myself.

Ive tried WinHex, HexCmp, Hex Editor Neo, Vim, Kdiff3, WinMerge, FlexHex, WinDiff, VBinDiff.

Some of the above seem to do what I want through their 'merge' features, but not for more than 3 files, and most of them crash with varying errors.